# Prevent a git commit which just has whitespace reformatting

Tags: git, github

I don't want to commit the code with only position change! Refer to below picture, the content is the same.

[image: Only position changed code]

It's not a content change but a meaningless position change which I don't want my code mate waste time on seeing these. In the past, I did it with "Discard" the changes. However, it's definitely not a proper approach since it can take a lot of time doing them.

I tried to search for relevant question and solutions but in vain. Am I the only unlucky guy encounter with this? Thanks for any help!!

Comment: If you don't want those changes to appear in the history, then: 1. Don't make them in the first place; or 2. Don't stage them (use e.g. `git stage -p` to edit which changes are included in the commit). In the latter case, be aware that they will add up over time, make some separate "styling" commits others can review and dismiss quickly. There is no way to make git not show changes you have made; note that whitespace matters in some languages.

Comment: In addition to the above, you can always rebase these formatting changes into the original commit where this code was written. Beware that this will change the history of your repository and will cause issues if other users are collaborating with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this, you could write a commit hook that examines each file to be comitted and checks if the change is just a whitespace change or not, and if its just a whitespace change, then reject the commit until such time that you have one or more non whitespace changes. But once the non whitespace changes go in, then they will show up in the history. Perhaps you can modify the tool that you use to look at the changes to filter out only white space changes.